# VHDL for loop in test bench to run truth table

Tags: vhdl

How would I do this in a VHDL test bench to run through a truth table for a multiplexer. Am I on the right track?

```
sel <= "00" after 100 ns, "01" after 200 ns, "10" after 300 ns, "11" after 400;

process (sel)
    variable p :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0); 
begin
    p := "0000"
    for j in "0001" to "1111" loop
        if j /= "1111" then p:= p + 1;
        wait for 5 ns; 
    end loop ;
end process;

x <= p;
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track, but I have not coded VHDL in over 12 years.

Answer (score 4):

Keep generation of `sel` (select) and `p` (data) together, since it is easier
to generate with the right timing if these are not decoupled in different
assigns or processes.  The loops may be created based on natural ranges.  The
process can then be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
...
process is
begin
  for sel_loop in 0 to 2 ** sel'length - 1 loop  -- 0 to 3 for sel'length = 2
    for p_loop in 0 to 2 ** p'length - 1 loop  -- 0 to 15 for p'length = 4
      sel <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sel_loop, sel'length));
      p   <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(p_loop, p'length));
      wait for 5 ns;
    end loop;
  end loop;
  wait;
end process;
```

Waveform is below.
[image]